# Java: Accessing elements of a row in a multidimensional array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, sum, element

I am doing a Java project and have constructed a Polygon like this:

```
DPolygons[NumberOf3DPolygons] = new DPolygon(new double[]{0, 2, 2, 0}, new double[]{0, 0, 0, 0},  new double[]{0, 0, 3, 3}, Color.red);
```

whereas the class DPolygon has the following constructor:

```
public DPolygon(double[] x, double[] y, double[] z, Color c)
{
    Screen.NumberOf3DPolygons++;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.c = c;
    createPolygon();
}
```

What I want to do is to calculate the sum of its z coordinates (which in this case will be = 6)
Here is what I had in mind:

```
sum = DPolygons[NumberOf3DPolygons].z[0]+DPolygons[NumberOf3DPolygons].z[1]+
                    DPolygons[NumberOf3DPolygons].z[2]+DPolygons[NumberOf3DPolygons].z[3];
```

But it gives a `NullPointerException` because it doesn't recognize `DPolygons[NumberOf3DPolygons].z[0]` as the first z value of the polygon and so on.

Can someone give me a clue what would be the right syntax for accessing each of these z elements? (Or how can I otherwise get that sum?)

Comment: have you considered using a for loop?

Comment: You increment `NumberOf3DPolygons` int he constructor; presumably you declared `DPolygons[]` as `new DPolygons[SOME_NUMBER]`, otherwise you would get an IndexOutOfBoundsException. There is no `DPolygons[NumberOf3DPolygons]`, only `DPolygons[NumberOf3DPolygons -1 ]`.

Comment: What does Screen.NumberOf3DPolygons++ do? Is it the same index that you use for DPolygons[NumberOf3DPolygons]?

Comment: @Toni92 Take a look at my solution below. Let me know whether it solves your problem.

Comment: @Kenney Thanks very much, I hadn't seen that :)

Comment: @svasa Yes, it is the same index. Screen.NumberOf3DPolygons is its syntax, because this row is written in the class DPolygon and not Screen, part of which NumberOf3DPolygons is.

Comment: @user3437460 Yes, I just marked it as accepted answer. Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to do is to calculate the sum of its z coordinates (which in this case will be = 6)

If I were you, I would create a method for the sum of z (or even the sum for x and y):

```
class DPolygon
{
    private double[] z;
    //Your other attributes here..
    //Your constructors here..

    public double getSumOfZ(){
        double sum = 0.0;
        if(z != null && z.length > 0)
            for(int i=0; i<z.length; i++)
                sum += z[i];
        return sum; 
    }
}
```

An example, if you have an array of 3D Polygons:

```
//Outside the class (for e.g. from the main method):
DPolygon poly1 = new DPolygon(new double[]{0, 2, 2, 0}, new double[]{0, 0, 0, 0},  new double[]{0, 0, 3, 3}, Color.red)};
DPolygon poly2 = new DPolygon(new double[]{0, 2, 2, 0}, new double[]{0, 0, 0, 0},  new double[]{0, 0, 3, 3}, Color.red)};
DPolygon poly3 = new DPolygon(new double[]{0, 2, 2, 0}, new double[]{0, 0, 0, 0},  new double[]{0, 0, 3, 3}, Color.red)};

DPolygons[NumberOf3DPolygons] polygons3D = {poly1, poly2, poly3};
```

To access the sum of z from a particular 3D polygon:

```
polygons3D[0].getSumOfZ();   //Get sum of z from first polygon
```

---

> But it gives a NullPointerException because it doesn't recognize DPolygons[NumberOf3DPolygons].z[0] as the first z value of the polygon and so on.

There are 2 possibilities for the `NullPointerException` to occur in your case:

1. You didn't initialize the array of z in DPolygon class.
2. The DPolygon element you are using from the array is null.

Ensure you initialize the `z array` from DPolygon class:

```
class DPolygon
{
    //Your other attributes here..
    private double[] x,y,z;
    public DPolygon(){
        initCoordinates();    //Init all arrays in the constructor 
    }

    //Initialize all x,y,z arrays.
    private void initCoordinates(){
        x = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
        y = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
        z = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    }
}
```

Comment: You will only need to change the return type of getSumOfZ() from void to double ;)

Comment: @Toni92 Yup, careless mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int i=0; i<DPolygons.length; i++){
        //If you have some condition, you can put over here.
        if(condition) {
        sum = DPolygons[i].z + sum; 
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is not correct. Read the question properly. OP asks about summing z coordinates of a particular Dpolygons not all z's out there. Also z is a double vector.

Answer (score 0):

Is the global variable z declare public?

```
public double z;
```

However, I would recomend creating a public method within Dpolygon class to retrieve global z value and using that getter instead of calling the property directly.

Inside the class:

```
public Double [ ] getZ (){return new Double (z[1],z [2],z [3]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Design the class as such...

```
public class DPolygon
{
    private double[] x, y, z;
    private Color color;

    public DPolygon(double[] x, double[] y, double[] z, Color color)
    {
        // Number of polygons best found in containing class.
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.color = Color;
    }

    public double[] getZ()
    {
        return z;
    }

    //...Other getters and setters.
}
```

Use an ArrayList with nested foreach loops to get all z values of all polygons...

```
ArrayList<DPolygon> dPolygons = new ArrayList<DPolygon>();

dPolygons.add(new DPolygon(new double[]{0, 2, 2, 3}, new double[]{0, 0, 0, 0},  new double[]{0, 0, 3, 3},Color.Red));

double sum=0;
for(DPolygon polygon : dPolygons)
{
    for (double zValue : polygon.getZ())
    {
        sum += zValue;
    }
}
```

For a particular polygon...

```
double sum2 = 0;
//Change index number to whatever specific polygon you want to sum.
int specificPolygon=0;
// Then to sum.
for(double zValue : dPolygons.get(specificPolygon).getZ())
{
    sum2 += zValue;
}
```

But if you're married to an array...

```
DPolygons[] dPolygons = new DPolygons[numberOfPolygons];

dPolygons[0] = new DPolygon(new double[]{0, 2, 2, 3}, new double[]{0, 0, 0, 0},  new double[]{0, 0, 3, 3},Color.Red)
//...Adding other polygons

// For single polygon
double sum3 = 0;
// As before, set specificPolygon equal to the index of the polygon you want.
int specificPolygon = 0;
for(double zValue : dPolygons[specificPolygon].getZ())
{
    sum3 += zValue;
}
```

The problem with the last approach is that you need to know the amount of polygons on the screen when the array is initialized. You can't dynamically add more at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There are two more neat concepts to introduce on the topic: [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) and, new in Java 1.8, [Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html) of [Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html).

Using a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) will do away with NullPointerExceptions caused by trying to manage dynamic arrays using global variables.
In your case, incrementing `Screen.NumberOf3DPolygons` in the constructor of `DPolygon` is not the right place for it. What happens if you construct another `DPolygon` and not add it to that array? You would want to make that variable consistent with how many elements are added to the list, using an `add` method in a object that manages the array. Luckily this is already done for us in the Java Collections classes.

Here's a working reproduction of the relevant code demonstrating using Collections, and another goodie: a one-liner to calculate the sum of the z coordinates.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main1
{
    public static class Screen
    {
        List<DPolygon> polygons = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static class DPolygon
    {
        private double[] x, y, z;

        private Color c;

        public DPolygon( double[] x, double[] y, double[] z, Color c )
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
            this.c = c;
        }

        public double sumZ()
        {
            return Arrays.stream( z ).sum();
        }

    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Screen screen = new Screen();

        screen.polygons.add(
            new DPolygon(
                new double[] { 0, 2, 2, 0 },
                new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                new double[] { 0, 0, 3, 3 },
                Color.red ) );

        System.out.println( screen.polygons.get( 0 ).sumZ() );
    }
}
```

It is still possible that you get an IndexOutOfBoundsException when you try to use at least two of `x`, `y` and `z` for a particular index: we're not sure every point has 3 coordinates, since some array may be smaller than another. To make sure all points have 3 coordinates, you'd group them like this:

```
       screen.polygons.add(
            new Polygon(
                Color.RED,
                new double[] { 0, 0, 0 },
                new double[] { 2, 0, 0 },
                new double[] { 2, 0, 3 },
                new double[] { 0, 0, 3 } ) );
```

using this `DPolygon` class:

```
    public static class DPolygon
    {
        List<double[]> points = new ArrayList<>();

        Color color;

        public DPolygon( Color c, double[]... coords )
        {
            this.points = Arrays.asList( coords );
            this.color = c;
        }

        public double sumZ()
        {
            return points.stream().mapToDouble( ( p ) -> p[2] ).sum();
        }
    }
```

You could go even further and abstract the point to a

```
    public static class Point3D
    {
        double x, y, z;

        public Point3D( double x, double y, double z )
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }
    }
```

which is easily supported by changing `double[]` to `Point3D`, and `new double[]{ ... }` to `new Point3D( ... )`, and `( p ) -> p[2]` to `( p ) -> p.z`.

One more thing: the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) recommend that identifiers start with a capital letter only if they are classes, interfaces, enums, and such - they should not be used for parameters, local variables, or fields. Almost everyone will assume that `Screen.NumberOf....` is a static field in class `Screen` (after dismissing it being a nested class by seeing it used as an integer).
The idea is that if I type `com.Foo.Bar.baz.hmm` everyone knows that `com` is a package name, `Foo` is a class, `Bar` is the nested class `Foo$Bar`, `baz` is a static field in class `Bar`, and `hmm` is a field of object `baz`.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. This would for sure be the more elegant solution. I tried to upvote the post but I don't have enough reputation yet.